# For any three vectors $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^d$, we have $ \|y-z\|\cdot\|x\|\leq\|x-y\|\cdot\|z\|+\|z-x\|\cdot\|y\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, normed-spaces

Does anyone know a proof of the following problem?

Problem: Show that for any three vectors ${\bf x}, {\bf y}, {\bf z}\in \mathbb{R}^d$ the following holds,
$$ \|{\bf y} - {\bf z}\|\cdot \|{\bf x}\| \leq \|{\bf x} - {\bf y}\|\cdot \|{\bf z}\| + \|{\bf z} - {\bf x}\|\cdot\|{\bf y}\|.$$

All of the norms are Euclidean 2-norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any of $x,y,$ or $z$ is zero the result is trivial. So WOLOG assume that $x,y,$ and $z$ are all non-zero and let $a = x/\Vert x\Vert^2$, $b=y/\Vert y\Vert^2$, and $c = z/\Vert z\Vert^2$. We have $\left\Vert x-y\right\Vert=\frac{\left\Vert a-b\right\Vert}{\Vert a\Vert\Vert b\Vert}$, $\left\Vert z-x\right\Vert=\frac{\left\Vert c-a\right\Vert}{\Vert c\Vert\Vert a\Vert}$, and $\left\Vert y-z\right\Vert=\frac{\left\Vert b-c\right\Vert}{\Vert b\Vert\Vert c\Vert}$. Therefore, $$\left\Vert y-z\right\Vert\Vert x\Vert=\frac{\left\Vert b-c\right\Vert}{\Vert a\Vert\Vert b\Vert\Vert c\Vert}\\\leq\frac{\left\Vert a-b\right\Vert}{\Vert a\Vert\Vert b\Vert\Vert c\Vert}+\frac{\left\Vert c-a\right\Vert}{\Vert a\Vert\Vert b\Vert\Vert c\Vert}\\=\left\Vert x-y\right\Vert\Vert z\Vert + \left\Vert z-x\right\Vert\Vert y\Vert,$$ which completes the proof.

Comment: I think that $\left\Vert x-y\right\Vert=\frac{\left\Vert a-b\right\Vert}{\Vert a\Vert\Vert b\Vert}$ is wrong.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter We have $x=a/\Vert a\Vert^2$ and $y=b/\Vert b\Vert^2$. Therefore, $\left\Vert x-y\right\Vert^2=\left\Vert a/\Vert a\Vert^2 - b/\Vert b\Vert^2\right\Vert^2=\frac{1}{\Vert a\Vert^2}-2\frac{a^T b}{\Vert a\Vert^2\Vert b\Vert^2}+\frac{1}{\Vert b\Vert^2}=\frac{\left\Vert a-b\right\Vert^2}{\Vert a\Vert^2\Vert b\Vert^2}$.

Comment: You are right. I had missed the ${}^2$ in the denominator. Sorry.

Comment: Excellent proof! This is my favourite proof of the day. +1. How did you come up with the $a=x/\|x\|^2$ trick?

Comment: @user1551 The inequality is essentially [Ptolemy's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem#Ptolemy.27s_inequality) with some little differences. One of the standard proofs for the Ptolemy's inequality is to use [inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_inversion). What I wrote is basically expressing the given inequality in terms of the inverses with respect to the unit sphere.

Comment: @S.B. Thank you for the informative reply :-D