# How prove this $|a-b||c|\le|a-c||b|+|b-c||a|$ if $a,b,c$ are vectors?

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c$ are vector numbers,show that
$$|a-b||c|\le|a-c||b|+|b-c||a|$$

my idea: $a_{i},b_{i},c_{i}\in \mathbb{R}$
let
$$a=(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n})$$
$$b=(b_{1},b_{2},\cdots,b_{n})$$
$$c=(c_{1},c_{2},\cdots,c_{n})$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i}-b_{i})^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}c^2_{i}}\le\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i}-c_{i})^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}b^2_{i}}+\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(b_{i}-c_{i})^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^2_{i}}$$

I think follow is use Cauchy-Schwarz or Minkowski inequality. But I can't, I feel this inequality is interesting.

Comment: A very small hint: you could try to start with $|a-b|=|a-b+c-c|\leq |a-c|+|c-b|=|a-c|+|b-c|$ and so on. The idea is to produce the terms in the r.h.s. of your inequality through this trick.

Comment: no,if $x,y$ are vectors,we have $|x||y|\ge |xy|$,not $|x||y|=|xy|$

Comment: @math110: If $x$ and $y$ are vectors, $xy$ does generally not make sense.

Comment: @math110 [Duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/426649/35778)

Comment: let $x=(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}),y=(y_{1},y_{2},\cdots,y_{n})$,then we def:$xy=x_{1}y_{1}+x_{2}y_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}y_{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be viewed as an inequality about simplices in ${\mathbb R}^3$, as only the four points $a$, $b$, $c$, and $O$ are involved. It then says that the product of the length of any two opposite edges is at most equal to the sum of the two other such products.

In order to prove this we may assume
$$O=(0,0,0),\quad a=(a,0,0), \quad b=(b_1,b_2,h),\quad c=(c_1,c_2, h)\ ,$$
i.e., that $b\vee c$ is parallel to the plane $z=0$. We then have to prove that
$$\eqalign{|Oa||b-c|&\leq |Ob||a-c|+|Oc||a-b|\cr &
=\sqrt{|Ob'|^2+h^2}\sqrt{|a-c'|^2+h^2}+\sqrt{|Oc'|^2+h^2}\sqrt{|a-b'|^2+h^2}\ ,
\cr}\tag{1}$$
where we have put $(b_1,b_2,0)=:b'$, $\>(c_1,c_2,0)=:c'$. Note that $|b-c|=|b'-c'|$; therefore the left hand side of $(1)$ is independent of $h$. It follows that it is enough to prove $(1)$ for $h=0$, in which case it can be written as
$$|Oa||b'-c'|\leq |Ob'||a-c'|+|Oc'||a-b'|\ .$$
Now this is Euler's generalization of Ptolemy's equality about cyclic quadrilaterals to an inequality about arbitrary convex quadrilaterals, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral#Generalizations_of_the_parallelogram_law_and_Ptolemy.27s_theorem).